# Сделать SUM столбца по месяцам для каждого пользователя

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Есть таблица со столбцами

```
INT 'user_id', 
INT 'credit', 
INT 'date' (сюда записывается UNIX_TIMESTAMP значение вида "1436449352").
```

По этой таблице нужно для определенного 'user_id' сделать выписку по счету и посчитать сколько 'credit' у него содержится в таблице по месяцам.
То есть данные нужно получить в формате:

```
Январь 2015 => 5
Февраль 2015 => 15
```

И так далее.
При этом выводить месяца с нулевым результатом не обязательно.
Такие записи могут быть в таблице за несколько лет.
Важно получить результат с самой первой записи и до последней. Это не сложно.
Сложность в том, чтобы просчитать это по месяцам.
Как организовать данный запрос чистым MySQL?
Возможно уже где-то есть готовые решения или же альтернативы на php или yii2?

Comment: *INT 'date' (сюда записывается UNIX_TIMESTAMP значение)* - так это именно int или `datetime` ?

Comment: @splash58, тип поля INT, а хранится там TIMESTAMP в виде "1436449352". Просто заносится туда значение через код, а не триггером.

Comment: Если бы это была дата, то проще некуда. `select EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from date) m, sum(credit) 
       from t1 
       where id=1  
       group by m`. Плюс правильный формат месяц-год написать. А вот как ваш int в дату конвертить, не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8078/1

Создание и заполнение таблицы для теста

```
CREATE TABLE `data_user` (
        `user_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED,
        `credit` INT(11),
        `date` INT(10) UNSIGNED
    );

INSERT INTO `data_user`
    (`user_id`, `credit`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, 3, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-04')),
    (1, 5, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-05')),
    (1, 2, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-02-05')),
    (2, 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01')),
    (2, -5, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-30'))
;
```

Сам запрос

```
SELECT `user_id`,
       SUM(`credit`) AS `sum_credit`,
       DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%Y %m') AS `group_date`
FROM 
      `data_user`
GROUP BY 
     `user_id`, `group_date`
ORDER BY 
      `user_id`, `group_date`
```

Результат

```
user_id     sum_credit  group_date
1           8           2015 01
1           2           2015 02
2           -4          2015 01
```

**UPD**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8078/2

Для вывода количества записей по месяцам меняем запрос так

```
SELECT `user_id`,
       COUNT(`credit`) AS `sum_credit`,
       DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%Y %m') AS `group_date`
FROM 
      `data_user`
GROUP BY 
     `user_id`, `group_date`
ORDER BY 
      `user_id`, `group_date`
```

Результат

```
user_id     sum_credit  group_date
1           2           2015 01
1           1           2015 02
2           2           2015 01
```

Comment: Автор вопроса просил не сумму кредитов, а их количество - `COUNT`.

Comment: @pavelip, обновил под ваше уточнение ;)

Comment: @pavelip, я отредактировал вопрос. Нужен был SUM.

Comment: @white-imp ну, непостоянный вы какой :)

Comment: @Visman, спасибо!

Comment: @pavelip, рабочие моменты) Спасибо за внимательность :)

Answer (score 2):

Дополню [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444342/%D0%A1%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-sum-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F#comment469070_444342):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) as year_month, SUM (credit) as credit_sum 
FROM table
GROUP BY year_month
```

[Источник мудрости](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

Comment: Petr Abdulin, спасибо!